# Run a php file as service?

Tags: centos, startup, services

I created a .sh file and it is email.sh

In this email.sh file I have these lines

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/username/public_html/Worker.php
```

Now, I want to make that email.sh as a startup service in the server and this script always in the background of my Centos server.

Can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: "script always in the background of my Centos server" What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

To run a script on startup, use the @reboot mechanism in cron. Add this line to /etc/crontab:

```
@reboot root /usr/local/bin/email.sh &
```

Make sure the script is in /usr/local/bin. It will run until stopped, so it can stay in the background.

Comment: When I run that code, I got @reboot: command not found

Comment: you shall put it into /etc/crontab